# Where is the "Server Settings" Menu?

Tags: centos6

Salvete!  I just installed CentOS 6 on a new box, and am looking for the "Server Settings" menu in order to configure SAMBA.  I have a menu for System, and therein lie "Preferences" and "Administration" but no "Server Settings" and no "SAMBA".  I suspect the tutorials I have been reading do not reflect the default layout of CentOS 6.  Can anyone direct me, please?

Now, I can confirm that smb is installed, and that the service is definitely running.  However, I followed the guide at http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/sambaserver.shtml, but my system does not recognize `system-config-samba.`

There are many items in the "Server Settings" menu that I am missing on my CentOS 6 installation.  Maybe I have overlooked some package installation?  I intend to use this machine as a server for Asterisk, so I need it fitted out correctly.

[update]
This thread is relevant:  https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=32086&forum=56

Comment: `sudo yum install samba`

Comment: @jscott I *did* say that Samba was already installed AND running, you know.  But just to prove it, that commandline gives `Package samba-3.5.10-115.el6_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version ...Nothing to do
`

Comment: No you didn't state that at first. Your edit to the question changed it to ask *"Where is `system-config-samba` in CentOS6?"*.  In that case, the answer is, ["It's been deprecated"](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=36713&forum=56&post_id=159243#forumpost159243) so it's not available in CentOS6.  If you truly want `system-config-samba` on 6, you will need to learn command line as well -- because you'll need to build it from source.

Comment: @jscott - oh, but if you meant that the "Server Settings" menu is deprecated, then that is the answer to the question.  If you post that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yuk. GUIs on servers.

Comment: @jscott- oh, your comment wasn't in my page when I made the edit; my apologies, then, jscott; please take no offense (smiley). I prefer commandline, actually, but the tutorials I have found refer to the gui, which I knew in CentOS 4. I am moving from CentOS 4 to 6, and doing my first server installation here. I actually meant my question to be about the "Server Settings" menu, and not about SAMBA. I added the SAMBA bit as a clue towards illustrating what I thought was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Scott had the answer - in CentOS 6, the Server Settings menu has been deprecated - it is no longer available.  There is a settings menu, but it isn't the same.  The idea is that since CentOS is supposed to be an operating system for a SERVER, it doesn't need all the gui settings because everything is meant to be administered from the console.